# Laravel Nova - Confirmation dialog before form post

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a Item Nova resource. According to the requirement from the client, I need to setup a confirmation dialog when a new post is created.

If the amount field is higher than a certain value, there I need to ask user "Are you sure to proceed? You amount is higher than expected value".

Anyone implemented similar feature with Laravel Nova?

Comment: Hi , has anyone find out solution for this issue ?

Comment: I'm looking for this solution as well. Did you manage it?